# erreur fatale prestashop when copy link into private browser

Tags: hyperlink, fatal-error, prestashop-1.7

When i copy this link for example in private browser i have fatal error written and only this or in french Erreur Fatale, nothing in apache log could not put prestashop in debug mode because some plugins are broken.

[link to test](https://www.djuntu.com/fr/491-toalhita-dodot-dermoactive.html)

We are in Prestashop version 1.7.5 Any idea? it makes me crazy

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cookie whas only generated by going to homepage, so clear all cache was the solution here (cache in FTP)